# Account is not allowed to suggest edits

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

From the morning, I was unable to edit any posts . I got the 'edit' tab freezed on my side. I can't click it anymore. When I bring my cursor to it, it says : " Account is not allowed to suggest edits ".

Can I know the reason behind that ? .

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/155238), in particular:

> **What about abuse?**
>
> There are strict limits enforced. If a user (anonymous or registered) submits many rejected edits they will be automatically banned from suggesting edits for 7 days. The fixed size queue also helps protect us from abuse.

Comment: Dear sir, But what is the problem in rejecting ? . I have been patiently editing all the math equations and formatting them neatly again. I never have done a false edit or a stupid edit. You can look at the edit history of mine. Did I use any abusive language ?

Comment: A lot of your edits are rejected on the basis that they are too minor. Note that edits bump questions to the front page, which is a limited resource. We thus try not to make unnecessary edits. Stuff like enclosing a numeral `0` in dollar signs `$0$`, or changing `\frac` to `\dfrac` are not strictly speaking necessary, and your suggestions to those effects have been rejected. Having a large number of edit suggestions rejected means that you are not acquainted yet with the community norm on when to and when not to edit. Think of it as a rite-of-passage or learning experience.

Comment: If you look at [your suggested edits](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/9969/iyengar?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), you can see what happened to them.

Comment: @WillieWong : Ok sir, Thanks a lot for your comment, I like your beautiful character of conveying some information without hurting the person to whom you are conveying. I have a great respect towards you. Have a good time.

Comment: @J.M. : Yes, I now realized my fault, I thought that even minor improvements can make a great change, and now I realized that they are not that important. Thank you FYI.

Comment: @Iyengar: I mainly rejected your last edit because I found it too minor, but also because you added "Thank you" at the end. I find it offensive when people force certain mannerism onto others. I should add that I would probably reject edits which removed "Thank you" (unless made a substantial improvement) as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : No problem sir. I understood the situation. Thank you.