# Questions about edit posts and recent tags.

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I have two questions. 1) Why I cannot edit the posts of the other users and 2) Why I cannot view all the post from Recent Tags?-It shows me :
"You are on the Featured tab.
There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.
Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" my friend can view its but me, I cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I see the 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rTQN.png)
you've posted [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5099/questions-about-edit-posts-and-recent-tags/5103#comment20231_5103), it seems to me that you are asking why 
you can't even [suggest edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work).

In case many of your recent edit suggestions have been refused, you could be blocked from suggesting temporarily; see this question: [Account is not allowed to suggest edits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4672/account-is-not-allowed-to-suggest-edits). 
(I think that the same thing may happen if you've made many suggested edits in a short period, but I am not sure about this.)

When I check your [last suggested edits](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33954/iuli?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), 5 of 7 your suggestions from yesterday were rejected, so this seems as a plausible explanation for me.

---

About your question 2:

When you view [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) you have many possibilities how to view them: newest, top-voted, feature (=having a bounty), recently active, unanswered. If you then choose to view questions only from some tag, then the MSE software provides the same view you have been using previously.

So if you have viewed featured questions [on the main site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured) or on some tag, and then you switch to another tag, which does not have any featured questions (at the moment [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus?sort=featured&pagesize=50) is an example of such tag), you will get the message you mentioned:

> You are on the Featured tab.
>   There are no questions with an active bounty at the moment.
>   Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

The solution is simple - you just choose one of the tabs above: info, newest, faq, votes, active, unanswered. In this way you will get questions from the given tag (sorted by the criterion you choose; if you want to see recently active questions, you click on *active*). Which is basically what you were viewing when you got that message - you were viewing all questions from the given tag, which have an active bounty. Only there were no such questions at the moment.

(I did not make screenshot, but I hope from the text above and the links, it can be understandable, what I mean.)

Comment: I think you don't understand me. One of my friend has the reputation only 6 and only one badges and he can make modifications to the others questions(modifying latex errors). I upload [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8rTQN.png). The edit button is not active even if it was and others with less reputation than me have active this option. And when I had modified a question and what I improve was accepted by the person who ask the question I received +2. Could anyone block me ? Thanks :)

Comment: Thnaks:) I'm understanding now.

Answer (score 2):

The log of your suggested edit (as linked to by Martin Sleziak) shows that your editing activity mainly consists of inserting `\displaystyle` at the beginning of all *non-displayed* TeX formulas. That will *either* do nothing *or* render the formula wrong (because it will then be typeset according to the rules for displayed formulas depite *not being a displayed formula*).

Perhaps you should take the hint and stop suggesting edits that do nothing but break the TeX?

Comment: I haven't looked at the case under discussion, but it seems to me that one occasionally *wants* a non-displayed formula to be typeset according to the rules for displayed formulas. Why did Knuth give us \displaystyle, if he did not want us to use it?

Comment: @Gerry: I don't think Kunth gave us \displaystyle because he wanted _someone else_ to run around and mechanically insert it in front of _every_ formula, no matter whether it makes a difference there or not, and no matter whether the difference it makes is one that the author of the post desires.

Comment: You may be correct in your assessment of what OP has done - as I say, I haven't looked. But I read your answer as saying that it's *always* wrong to use \displaystyle because formulas that are not displayed should *never* be typeset according to the rules for displayed formulas. Perhaps I have misinterpreted what you wrote, but what you wrote doesn't seem to me to allow for the possibility that \displaystyle may occasionally do some good.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I have no problem with inserting \displaystyle in formulas where one, as the author of a post (or as someone who TeXifies a post whose author didn't do so), _specifically_ wants the rendering variant selected by that command. I do have a problem with someone else deciding that the author of the post _should_ have wanted that rendering, particularly when the "someone else" decides so completely without any discernible regard to the _content_ of the formulas as well as whether \displaystyle actually does something for the formula or not.

Comment: OK, I think I am at least 95% in agreement with you, and I'm happy to let the other 5% or less slide until such time as a case comes up warranting reopening of the discussion, if ever.

Answer (score 2):

Low quality edits happen, I have approved too many of them myself. It does not mean that they will be approved automatically always.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't edit other people's posts until 2000 reputation. See the [FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) for a complete description of what privileges you get at various reputation levels.
2. What do you mean by viewing all the posts from recent tags?

Comment: 1. But I could edit the questions. What I want to say is that if someone made a latex mistake I could correct it and now I cannot. 
2. For example , I like inequalities and one month ago when I clicked on the tag with name Inequalities all the inequalities were showed me, but now appears only the questions with bounty.

Comment: @Iuli: 1. That shouldn't have been the case. What is true is that you can currently edit community wiki posts as well as suggest edits which are approved or rejected by higher-rep users. 2. You just need to change the tab from "featured" back to "newest."

Comment: When can I edit again the latex errors ? I don't understand very well what you say in the previous comment at number one. Thanks:)

Comment: @Iuli: at 2000 rep, if the post is community wiki, or if you suggest an edit and it gets approved. (I don't know how suggesting edits works because I became a moderator before that feature existed.)

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Anyway it is strange about edit questions-because yesterday morning I could edit the questions but from yesterday evening I cannot.

Comment: Iuli, did you somehow lose 1100 points overnight?

Comment: BTW you only need 500 rep points to be able to retag question. @Iuli when you write you were able to edit a question, was it perhaps just editing tags and not the content of the question?